# trying to find customers and their total sales who have shopped for brand1 as well as brand2

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying to find the customer who have bought brand1 and brand 2 and also the total sum of the dollar value spent. I have made a sample data base which has all the details.
I am able to get the customers who have bought both the brands, but the dollar amount should equal to the the sum of dollar amount spend in brand 1 and brand 2.

this is the link to the sample database:

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8a478b5743099ea5c76acd08e22c0c53

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you can just use aggregation with an appropriate `having` clause:

```
select individual_id, sum(dollar_value_us)
from transaction_detail_mv
group by individual_id
having sum( case when brand_org_code = 'BRAND1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum( case when brand_org_code = 'BRAND2' then 1 else 0 end) > 0
```

Comment: I am also trying to get the actual data at the line item level. So I wanted to get a query which would not aggregate but show me the customer detail, quantity, txn_date, summed(dollar_value)

Comment: @SomiyaL . . . Your question is "I am trying to find the customer who have bought brand1 and brand 2 and also the total sum of the dollar value spent."  This is repeated in the title.  You should be clear when you ask questions.

Answer (score 1):

use corelated subquery

```
    select  individual_id, SUM (dollar_value_US) from 
transaction_detail_mv t1
where t1.brand_org_code IN ('BRAND1','BRAND2')

AND  EXISTS  (SELECT 1  
FROM TRANSACTION_DETAIL_MV t2 WHERE t1.individual_id=t2.individual_id
      and BRAND_ORG_CODE = 'BRAND2')
GROUP BY 
individual_id

INDIVIDUAL_ID   SUM(DOLLAR_VALUE_US)
  1                40
  2                22
  5                22
```

Comment: The sum should be 40 for customer_id 1. need the total where the customer has bought both brand 1 and brand 2

Comment: @SomiyaL check now sum is 40

Comment: yes it does but I am trying to add txn_date as well